# Working with file and directories paths in c++11?

Tags: c++11

Working with file and directories paths in c++11?

I am trying to catch up, it has been long time since c++.

What should I use: the boost filesystem library, or there are better ways in c++11,
for the following tasks:

1. get files from directory string
2. manipulate file/directory paths
   ...

Comment: boost::filesystem is my choice. I like it for portability.

Comment: wow, boost still rocks?! I thought c++11 should have its own such mechanisms.

Comment: No, there is no `filesystem` library in C++11, and, moreover,  I can't find any information about `filesystem` in C++1y. So, using `boost` is the best choice, I guess.

Comment: Can someone please post this as answer so that I can accept it and make this question useful for others?

Comment: AFAIK, the Standard Library Filesystem will be based on boost.filesystem v3 and published as a somewhat stand-alone standard / optional (not included in the C++1y/1z standard itself). [n3803](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3803.pdf) is the most recent public draft.

Answer (score 0):

For now, [Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem) is your best bet. It's [proposed](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3940.html) for a future version of C++, but it also doesn't have support for some POSIX features (opened file descriptors, openat) that improve security and performance, so it may change before it gets into the standard.

Answer (score 0):

The standard filesystem library would be best - once it comes out.
Sadly I haven't seen any other currently available c++11 implementations.

Instead, TinyDir is a small c dependency I like to use for these kind of tasks:

https://github.com/cxong/tinydir

I personally really like it's simplicity and portability. (linux + windows)